# Haskell Criterion: Could not load module, hidden package

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-criterion

When I do exactly what [this Criterion tutorial](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/tutorial.html) says to do to get started, I get an error. What am I doing wrong? Is the tutorial wrong? If so, is there a place that I can learn the right way to use Criterion?

Specifically, as the tutorial says, I ran the following in command line:

```
cabal update
cabal install -j --disable-tests criterion
```

This ran without error. Then I copied exactly the example program in the tutorial:

```
import Criterion.Main

-- The function we're benchmarking.
fib m | m < 0     = error "negative!"
      | otherwise = go m
  where
    go 0 = 0
    go 1 = 1
    go n = go (n-1) + go (n-2)

-- Our benchmark harness.
main = defaultMain [
  bgroup "fib" [ bench "1"  $ whnf fib 1
               , bench "5"  $ whnf fib 5
               , bench "9"  $ whnf fib 9
               , bench "11" $ whnf fib 11
               ]
  ]
```

I put that into a file called benchTest.hs, and then I used the command line to compile the program exactly as it says in the tutorial, but with benchTest in place of Fibber, which is what they called it. Specifically, the I ran the following in the command line:

```
ghc -O --make benchTest
```

This resulted in this error:

```
benchTest.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not load module `Criterion.Main'
    It is a member of the hidden package `criterion-1.5.13.0'.
    You can run `:set -package criterion' to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    It is a member of the hidden package `criterion-1.5.13.0'.
    You can run `:set -package criterion' to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Criterion.Main
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Could you try `cabal v2-install --lib -j --disable-tests --package-env=. criterion` instead of your `cabal install` and compile the same way. All in the same directory (important!).

Comment: It may be helpful if you post the versions of cabal and GHC you use. It seems like you use really old version of cabal (pre 3.0).

Comment: Yes, the tutorial is wrong. It was written for an old version of `cabal`.

Comment: Okay so a) yes, it was a very old version of cabal (2.4 something) and I've updated it now to 3.6.2.0, b) Artem's suggestion for a different install command works, and c) that command also suffices without `--package-env=.`, is there a reason I should keep that there even if I am able to compile a program using criterion without it?

Comment: @embradley I posted a long answer below. I hope it's not prohibitively long…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short history of Cabal evolution

Through its history, Cabal has gone through a big transformation of how it
works, which is commonly denoted as `v1-` commands vs. `v2-` commands; e.g.
since Cabal 2 you can say `cabal v1-install` or `cabal v2-install`. What happens
when you say just `cabal install` depends on the Cabal version: Cabal 2 will use
`v1-install` by default while Cabal 3 will use `v2-install`. The change in
defaults reflects the preferred mode of operation. So much so, `v1` has become
basically unmaintained. I don't expect it to be removed soon because there is a
group of hard proponents of the old way. But personally I think that, first, the
new way (fun fact you can use `cabal new-install` as a synonym) is technically
superior, and second, that newcomers should just use it because it's better
documented and you can have more luck in getting help with it (in many cases,
it's easier to help because of the above-mentioned superiority)

### Why `v1` was subsumed by `v2` (in a nutshell)

The main trouble you can run in with `v1` is incompatible dependencies across
several projects. Imagine, you work on project `A` that depends on package `X`
of version `42`, and, at the same time you're starting with project `B` that
also depends on `X` but of version `43`. Guess what: you can't `v1-build` the
two projects on the same machine without wiping out `cabal`'s cache in between.
This was the way it worked in dark ages (from the middle of 2000s to yearly
2010s).

After that, *cabal sandboxes* arrived. They allowed you to build our imaginary
projects `A` and `B` with less hussle but the interface was not great and, more
importantly, every sandbox was independent and, therefore, held a big chunk of
repetitive binaries; e.g. `A` and `B` could depend also on `Y` of the same
version `13`, so there's theoretically no need to build and store `Y` twice,
but that's exactly what cabal sandboxes would do.

Cabal `v2` arrived in the late 2010s and brought exactly that: isolation between
projects via an (also recent) GHC feature called *environment files* and sharing
of build artifacts via *Cabal store* (so that you don't store many copies of the same thing).

### Environments and `v2-install`

You can create a separate environment for
every project (`A`, `B`, etc.) by doing

```
cabal v2-install --lib X-42 --package-env=.
```

in the directory of the respective project. Couple notes on the syntax:

1. `v2-` can be omitted in Cabal 3 because it's the default;
2. The order of flags is not important as long as `install` goes right
   after `cabal`;
3. `--lib` is important, because by default you get only executables (that's
   what happens with `criterion`: the package holds an executable);
4. `--package-env=.` means: create a GHC environment file in the current
   directory (hence `.`). If the command succeeds you will notice a new
   ("hidden" on Linux) file in the current directory, named something like
   `.ghc.environment.x86_64-linux-9.0.2`. This is the file that tells all
   subsequent calls to GHC in this directory where to search for the libraries compiled by Cabal
   and stored in… *Cabal store* (on Linux it's the `~/.cabal/store` directory by
   default). In principle, you can use other than `.` values for environments,
   and if the value doesn't correspond to a path, it will be a named
   environment. [More details in Cabal reference manual…](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-commands.html#adding-libraries-to-ghc-package-environments) In practice, I find
   99.99% cases perfectly served by `--package-env=.`.
5. `X-42` means the package `X` of version `42` should be added to the newly
   created environment. You can omit the version (you will get "some compatible
   version"), and you can list more than one package.

### What `cabal v2-install --lib` means if no environment specified

It means *the `default` environment*. There is a single shared environment called
`default`. It has the same very problem that `v1` had (see above). So, in
practice it could work but it will be very fragile, especially if you get into
the "project `A` and project `B`" situation described above. Even if you only
work with one project now, I suggest using `--package-env` because it's future
proof.

### Why the initial error

As you say, you were using Cabal 2 and therefore `v1-install` initially and saw
the dreaded "hidden package" error — what's the reason for this? Honestly, I
have no idea. And I doubt it's easy to figure without rolling back to that older
Cabal version and experimenting more. As I say above, `v1` is not really maintained
anymore, and even if it looks like a bug in Cabal (which is perfectly possible
especially with earlier releases in the Cabal 2 line), no one will probably
bother about it.

### Isn't it sad that old tutorials don't work anymore

It is. Unfortunately, the software technology has to develop to make the world a
better place to live (see the reasons for `v2` above again). Sometimes this
development has to break backward compatibility. Ideally, we'd go and update all
educational materials and manuals to reflect the change but that's hardly
possible. Sigh. New users of Haskell has to be careful and creative with respect
to the `v1` to `v2` shift and try to get a basic understanding of `v2` early on
and try to apply it to the good but old tutorials that are still out there.

### Are environments the best approach?

Some of the designers and proponents of `v2` argue that environment files are a
too subtle of a feature. As a ("proper") alternative, they suggest creating a
full-fledged cabal package for every project you start. This amounts to calling
`cabal init`, which will create a `<project-name>.cabal` file in the current
directory, and maintaining the `.cabal` file, including the list of package
dependencies there; you will also use `cabal v2-build` to build the project (instead of directly calling GHC).

While more robust, unsurprisingly, this idea doesn't sleep
well with many people who use Haskell to try a lot of small independent things:
it feels lame to create a whole "package" every time. Well, it's just one extra
file in practice, and it's not even extra if you compare it to the
environments-based approach I described above, which also maintains one extra
file, but in that case you don't ever need to edit it by hand (unlike the
`.cabal` file). All in all, in the scenarios of "trying one small thing" I find
the environments-based approach working better for me. But it does have its
limitations compared to the package-based approach, notably, it's [hard to figure out](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/7832)
how to get profiling versions of dependencies in the environment. But that's a
story for another day…

You can find more discussion about how `cabal v2-install --lib` can be improved in [Cabal issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6481).

If you want to follow the officially blessed way of doing things (i.e. via a package), please, take a minute to read [the Getting Started section of the Cabal manual](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/getting-started.html) — it's very clear and shows exactly an example of simple application with a dependency on an external package.